# bootstrap icon float to most right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My icon always float to the most right.

See image below :
[image: See image below.]
It doesn't stick beside of the input.

My code is :

```
 <div class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("date", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10">


                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.pdate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.pdate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is your HTML the same as you can see in the Bootsrap reference? http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: change `<div class="col-md-10">` to `<div class="col-md-2">`

Comment: i guessed i found the problem. visual studi generated this line of css in the site.css input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why are using nested form-group classes in your code

May be you added some css on **input field** so remove that.

Just remove this css from below answer and see the difference:

```
 #datepk{
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```css
.input-group-addon{
  width: 0%;
}
#datepk{
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

</style>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class='col-sm-6'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
      <input id="datepk"type='text' class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
  

  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yea i found out that too. and i removed the additional form group as well.Thanks

Comment: @AizhongChen Welcome dude!

Answer (score 0):

You are using '`.input-group-addon`' class. In this class there is a property `width: 1%;` (from `bootstrap.css`)

And display property is table-cell;

So, your

```
<span class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
</span>
```

is taking only `1%` width of whole `width`. If you omit this property your problem will be solved I think.

Just override `.input-group-addon` `width: 1%;` property.

```
.input-group-addon
{
  width: 0%;
}
```

Or give whatever width you want to give him. :-)